# Why does ios app crash with "Library not loaded"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

My project includes 1 xcframework which i added under "Embed Frameworks" with:

- "copy only when installing" selected
- "code sign on copy" selected
- xcframework is added under "link binary with libraries"

Runpath search paths includes "@executable_path/Frameworks"

Im getting the following crash on device only. Simulator works fine.

Why can't the app find the framework?

> dyld[5303]: Library not loaded:
> @rpath/SharedResources.framework/SharedResources
>
> Referenced from:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/42FFED53-5677-4A0E-A795-FD1A6A1C6FD5/Pro
> Dev.app/Pro Dev
>
> Reason: tried:
> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/42FFED53-5677-4A0E-A795-FD1A6A1C6FD5/Pro
> Dev.app/Frameworks/SharedResources.framework/SharedResources' (no such
> file),
> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/42FFED53-5677-4A0E-A795-FD1A6A1C6FD5/Pro
> Dev.app/Frameworks/SharedResources.framework/SharedResources' (no such
> file),
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/SharedResources.framework/SharedResources'
> (no such file)

Comment: hey you got that working ?